# How to get the module connected to a gate?

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

Inside a module, I can get a `cGate` pointer calling the method:

```
const cGate* cModule::gate  (   const char *    gatename, int   index = -1)
```

But once obtained the `cGate` pointer, I don't see a way to get the associate module that is connected (in output) to the gate. I don't see it in the `cChannel` class either. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `cGate::getPathStartGate()` and `cGate::getPathEndGate()` methods. Depending on the direction of the connection those will give you the endpoint gates (it will follow the connections even across module boundaries until it finds a simple module at the other side of the connection chain).
(`cGate::getNextGate()` and `cGate::getPreviousGate()` gives only the next/prev gate on the chain)

Once you have the `cGate` object from the other side, you can get the module using `cGate::getOwnerModule()`